# Cypress: type combination of keys and keyCodes

Tags: javascript, cypress, end-to-end

I need to navigate through the keyboard pressing ALT+F10.

I know that is possible to type commands like this:

`cy.focused().type('{alt}')`

How can I add the F10 key to this command?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try `.trigger` with `altKey:true` (for pressing down `alt`) and `keyCode: 121` for the F10 key:

```
cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { altKey: true, keyCode: 121, which: 121 })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to read the documentation on [Key Combinations](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Key-Combinations)

I can't test it right now but I suppose following code could work:

```
cy.get('input').type('{alt}', { release: false }) // this should keep alt pressed
cy.get('input').trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 121, which: 121 }) // trigger F10 keycode
```

Anyway, read the documentation about `{ release: false })` option of `.type`, you should find your answer there.

---

**Note:** You cannot type F10 using {f10} because it's not built in Cypress yet. The special characters which are built in are described [HERE](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Arguments).